# Unable to deploy angularjs app in apache webserver using virtual hosts

Tags: angularjs, apache, deployment

This is on Mac OS X El Captain

I am trying to deploy a web application built in Angularjs on Apache web server.

The folder is created in /Users/username/Sites/7MinutesWorkout

For the same in order to enable virtual host, i uncommented the below line from httpd.conf

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Also in httpd-vhosts.conf, included the below snippet

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/<username>/Sites/7MinutesWorkout"
ServerName 7MinutesWorkout.com
ServerAlias www.7MinutesWorkout.com
ServerAdmin <username>@dummy.com
ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/7MinutesWorkout.com_error_log"
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/7MinutesWorkout.com_access_log" common
<Directory>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also made entry in /etc/hosts as

```
127.0.0.1    7MinutesWorkout.com
127.0.0.1    www.7MinutesWorkout.com
```

Restarted apache by the command sudo apachectl restart

But when i try to access the site, i get the error page, this site cannot be reached.

On executing the command

```
apachectl configtest
```

gives the output as AH00526: Syntax error on line 47 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
Directory directive requires additional arguments

There is only one entry as of now in the httpd-vhosts.conf as specified above.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with the `Require all granted` which needs to be present.
Here is the relevant part of my config, which works

```
<Directory>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
 Order Allow,Deny
 Allow from all
#     Allow from 127.0.0.1
#     Allow from ::1
#     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```